# Why does the second switchMap execute hundreds of times on subscribe?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Here is the minimal code that reproduces the problem:

```js
import { defer, BehaviorSubject, of } from "rxjs";
import { shareReplay, switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";

const oneRandomNumber = defer(() => of(Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)));

const cache = { key: oneRandomNumber.pipe(shareReplay(1)) };

export const swr = () =>
  new BehaviorSubject(null).pipe(
    switchMap(() => cache.key),
    switchMap(number => {
      console.log(number); // WHY DOES THIS EXECUTE SO MANY TIMES?!
      return cache.key;
    })
  );

swr().subscribe();
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-sky-np06v?file=/src/index.ts)

I would expect to only see one number logged. Not hundreds.

The problem disappears if you do any of the following things:

- remove `shareReplay(1)`
- you don't use the `cache` object, but just use `oneRandomNumber.pipe(shareReplay(1))` directly
- don't use `switchMap` twice

But my eventual code needs all of those things.

Comment: I see your demo is using rxjs `7.0-beta`; Switching to `6.6.4` resolves the issue.

Comment: Huh, you're right. Okay I just reported the bug and went back to version 6.

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/6151

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems work as expected. In this code you replay observable each time it used, - it's what `shareReplay` exactly do. And with your two `switchMap` operators it goes to infinity replaying job and falls to hell, because of each other.

Reason for that - your first `switchMap` operator doesn't have endpoint, like `take(1)` or something in that kind.

If you though buffer size do any job here, it's wrong. Buffer works only on multiple subscriptions, not multiple observable usage in that case.

Comment: Or just separate your observable with ShareReplay and without.